# Django UserProfile extension

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using the UserProfile method in my models to extend the user.

If I want to allow the user a title ie 'Mr' and a middle initial 'A', what is the standard pratice for this?

At present in its raw format, i enter a firstname and last name and then scroll down to select the title and input any initials.

Is it possible to combine the user and userprofile fields?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom ModelForm with something like that:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['title', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'all other fields']
```

If you don't want to list all fields, you can fiddle with that keyOrder, it's just a list:

```
correct_order = ['title', 'first_name', 'middle_name']
other_fields = filter(lambda f: f not in correct_order, self.fields.keyOrder)
self.fields.keyOrder = correct_order + other_fields
```

You can also use this form in your admin.